# Hook into call_user_func_array - possible?

Tags: php

Is it possible to hook into php function (like `register_shutdown_function` hooks into `exit`)

I am interested to hook into `call_user_func_array`.

Does [`hookphp`](https://github.com/sciactive/hookphp) or like that makes that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the hook?

Comment: Why only `call_user_func_array()`? What if the function is called normally, instead of indirectly?

Comment: `hookphp` looks like it's only for class methods, not normal functions.

Comment: hookphp appears to only work on classes. You would need to implement a solution using the [ADP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) extension, which is not intended for production use, but would provide you with `rename_function()` and `override_function()` to which you can then change the function.behavior, when it is called directly.

Comment: @fyrye please post it as answer and i will upvote it.

Comment: @T.Todua I'd need to know more about what you're attempting to accomplish to post an appropriate answer. Since I don't really condone the usage of APD, and PECL no longer maintains it, I do not consider it a proper solution. Along with the addition of the splat operator `$callable(1, ...[2, 3]);`, PHP 5.6+ has made its use obsolete.

Comment: @fyrye Actually, I work with wordpress, where everything is hookable. it means, when in any project/application, there is `call_something_function($par1,$par2)`, you can bind another function in that (so, your hooked function will be executed with same parameters). wanted to know if native php has that too. However, I dont want extra packages (like PECL or whatever)

Comment: I see, the short answer would be no, PHP does not *currently* provide that functionality. It would be up to you to develop a layer of abstraction, like Wordpress and other Full-Stack frameworks do.